# React native fetch issue in new project

Tags: react-native

Following [React Native Tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html#content), I am running into an issue with fetch() that I do not understand. I haven't been able to find a post to shed light on this.

`fetch()` doesn't seem to be making ah https request, and the `Promise` isn't responding to the `then()`.

The code at question:

```
url = "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World";
fetch(url).then(function(resp) {
  return resp.json();
})
.then(function(json){
  console.log(json);
});
```

Running this on localhost debugger-ui returns the following, but there's no `console.log(json)` output:

```
Promise {_32: 0, _8: null, _89: Array[0]}
```

Running this on chrome dev tools console outside of react native debug ui:

```
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
    Object {id: 1296269, name: "Hello-World", full_name: "octocat/Hello-World", owner: Object, private: false…}
```

I'm using the most recent packages installed as shown in the tutorial. My packager is running `node_modules/react-native/packager/launchPackager.command ; exit;`, and I can see the `http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle`. To verify that the https request are made, I monitored a local web server logs when running `fetch()` on localhost url.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why, but `fetch` is now working for me in an app, and still not in the debug console.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like I just encounter the same problem with you.

And your question kind of give me some hint to understand what happened, for the following code:

```
fetch(url, option).
then((res) => {
  const json = res.json();
  console.log(json);
  return json;
}).then(json => {
  console.log(json);
  return json;
});
```

The first `json` in `console.log` is actually a `Promise`. So it won't print the correct content. But the second `console.log` will have the correct `json` because the `then` function will resolve the promise returned.